# Merging angular2/4 files to Node.js server

Tags: node.js, angular

Request you all to please help me on below question:

Premise:
I have created a working application- client-side using angular2 and server-side using node.js (Rest services are used). Both client and server using the different default port 4200 and 3000 respectively. Since this application is not that big and my company doesn't want to open any extra port for security reason hence I was suggested to move all angular files to node.js server which then thereafter host the entire application.

Question:
How can I move all my file from angular2 and add them to node.js so that it works as it was working before? There are many dependencies exist in angular2, similarly, it bootstrap components in a different way then how can I use angular files in node.js?

Any suggestion or solution are deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can you `ng build`. This command will generate a `dist` folder and your node server can read it. If you use `expressjs` you can see the example [MEAN Stack (Angular 5) CRUD Web Application Example](https://www.djamware.com/post/5a0673c880aca7739224ee21/mean-stack-angular-5-crud-web-application-example) .

Comment: Yes, I am using Express and I tried like this: app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));
app.use('/books', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist'))); but then which file I make as a index.html. Angular bootstrap all components based on AppModule.ts but then what should I used as starting index file if I put dist folder in public folder of node.js

Comment: i only use `ng build` and add ` app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist'))); ` in the app.js. So the node server will use the static in `dist` and it will start the index.html . you don't need to config them.

Comment: Where should I add 'dist' folder in node. Should it be in public folder or at root level.